# Laravel reCAPTCHA Undefined index: 127.0.0.1

Tags: php, laravel, localhost, recaptcha

I am trying to integrate Google reCAPTCHA into my Laravel website by following this [tutorial](https://medium.com/self-modifying-code/using-recaptcha-v3-and-laravel-in-2020-645e5ffec6c9). I have completed all of the steps, but now when I try to submit the contact form I get this error in my browser: `Undefined index: 127.0.0.1`.

The error is coming from the following line of code inside of my ReCaptchaRule.php file:

```
$resp = $recaptcha->setExpectedHostname($_SERVER['127.0.0.1'])->setScoreThreshold(0.5)>verify($value, $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
```

I have already added "127.0.0.1" and "localhost" in my Google reCAPTCHA admin panel. I thought maybe the error had something to do with me testing reCAPTCHA on 127.0.0.1, so I pushed the changes to my live website, but now I am getting a `500 | Server Error` response when I try to submit the contact form.

Comment: Actually looking at link you weren't supposed to change that line at all `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` is correct.

Comment: So are you saying I need to replace the `$_SERVER['127.0.0.1']` with `$_SERVER[print_r($_SERVER)]`?

Comment: "Set the hostname to your SERVER_NAME. This should match the domain you listed in the Google ReCaptcha admin console."

Comment: No, `print_r($_SERVER)` is for debugging. It will output all `$_SERVER` values you have available. Look at your tutorial again, you've made an error.

Comment: `SERVER_NAME` is an acceptable index for `$_SERVER`. I'm not clear what they meant by that line but the code below, unchanged, should function. Use `print_r` and you can see.